# Problems with RSelenium and ChromeDriver - "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version X"

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I'm having a difficult time getting `RSelenium` to work with my `ChromeDriver` in R v4.1.2. Initially, I installed the `ChromeDriver v97` because I had Chrome v97 running on my Mac as my browser. However, despite installing the `v97 ChromeDriver`, I would get an error every time that read

`Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 98`

So I did some research and everything I read said I could either upgrade Google Chrome or downgrade my driver. I tried both. I uninstalled the driver and installed an earlier version (`v96`) but it still gave me the exact same error. Then I tried upgrading my Chrome browser, but it said it was up to date and that no upgrade was available. So I just figured I'd wait until `v98` was ready to install. As soon as `v98` was out, I upgraded my browser to `Chrome v98` and `Selenium` with the `ChromeDriver` ran smoothly without issues. I haven't changed anything since. It ran for a couple of days, but now, all of a sudden, I'm getting the error again but now it says

```
 "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99"
```

But I have not upgraded my `ChromeDriver` since installing the `v97` driver. It seems as though the driver must have some code in it that checks what the most current version of Chrome is (even if that is a Beta release) and requires that I have it, regardless of which driver or browser I have installed. Has anyone come across this issue before? Any idea of how I can resolve this? I cannot upgrade to `v99`, it's not available yet, and uninstalling my `ChromeDriver` and reinstalling a previous version doesn't seem to do anything either.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know the chrome version use,

```
binman::list_versions("chromedriver")

$win32
 [1] "85.0.4183.87"  "86.0.4240.22"  "87.0.4280.20"  "87.0.4280.88"  "88.0.4324.27"  "91.0.4472.101" "91.0.4472.19"  "92.0.4515.107" "92.0.4515.43"
```

Then you can try the versions which works for you,

```
library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome",port = 9537L, chromever = "96.0.4664.45")
```

or else you can use firefox,

```
driver = rsDriver(port = 4841L, browser = c("firefox"))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to resolve the issue by changing the 'chromever' in the rsDriver() function.

Comment: Even when I tell rsDriver() which chromever I want it to use (I upgraded my chromedriver to 113.0.5672.63 because my browser is 113), RSelenium fails because it bizarrely tries to recreate the mac64_m1 directory with an old 105 chromedriver version in it, as if it's completely ignoring which version I'm telling it to use. The 113 chromedriver is already there in the right directory. When I call binman::list_versions("chromedriver") it lists the 113 version. But RSelenium doesn't seem to care. It just automatically attempts to recreate the directory with an older (incompatible) driver.

Answer (score 1):

The Mac has problems because there are two architectures (Intel and M1), and the code that loads the RSelenium driver hasn't been updated since the M1 came out.

This patch https://github.com/ropensci/wdman/pull/26 fixed the issue for me, working on an Intel Mac.  You should also see this issue:  https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/221, which offers some code to sequentially try drivers until it finds one that works.

Comment: Wow this might be why I'm still having a problem even after upgrading my driver and trying to specify it in the rsDriver() function, as recommended above by Nad Pat. I'll try the devtools RSelenium since that fix you linked to appears to have been incorporated in the development version.

Comment: @JamesCutler:  I think the latest problem I've had is different:  the code to load the driver gets confused by a license file.  I don't know if that's fixed in the Github version, but it's still an issue in the CRAN version.  It's really a `wdman` or `binman` issue rather than an `RSelenium` issue, but it's discussed here:  https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/274

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just switching to Firefox, because no matter what I do (e.g., I've fixed the chromedriver problem), something ends up having a problem. Now it's ports. With Firefox, it worked like charm immediately after my first try. You just set chromever to NULL and browser to "firefox".