# Dynamic web scraping with R Selenium alternatives

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

May I ask if there are alternatives to RSelenium package for dynamic web scraping?. The package only accepts Chrome version 108 and mine is 107. Rvest alone returns 0.

I need to scrape profiles age data using search from this link.
https://www.healthgrades.com/

Also, I would be grateful if you have any suggestions to run RSelenium in version 107

Comment: That's a persistent problem with me as well. Some possible solutions float around, but they are not always helpful. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71003899/problems-with-rselenium-and-chromedriver-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-su

Comment: Did you try to use firefox?

Comment: It worked with me using instructions in the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to connect to the website with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)

shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.healthgrades.com/")
remDr$screenshot(TRUE)
```